# YQL and oAuth while accessing community tables confused me!

Tags: php, web-services, oauth, authorization, yql

Imagine that I want to access somebody's emails using YQL:

1. I get consumer key and secret from yahoo
2. make a three legged authorization
3. access to user's mails.

Now I'm going to access something private from another table from community ones like `twitter.status.retweets`.

**The Question**: Should I use the consumer key got from yahoo to authorize my user? And then YQL gives me an URL from Twitter to redirect my user to it if I do so?
Or should I get another from Twitter and use it to auth my user?

I'm new to oauth and YQL authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each service has its own authentication (Yahoo Mail and Twitter in your example), so your application would need to manage separately for each service:

- Sign up for developer key
- Authorize your user (OAuth 3-leg authorization)
- Make signed calls on user's behalf (YQL or other)

You can search around for some good examples and introductory articles for [using YQL with Twitter](https://www.google.com/search?q=yql+twitter+oauth) and [using YQL with Yahoo! Mail APIs](https://www.google.com/search?q=yql+mail+oauth).